# Read digits from non-separated characters into int array in C

Tags: c, arrays, io

I am trying to read digits from non-separated input of characters into an int array. Sample input and output:

```
Input: 12a34b56 C7d8E9
Output: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Here is my attempt:

```
int check_digit (char c) {
    if ((c>='0') && (c<='9')) return 1;
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    int numArray[1000], tempChar, c = 0;

    tempChar = getchar();

    while ( tempChar != EOF ) {
        if ( check_digit(tempChar) ) {
            numArray[c] = tempChar - '0';
            c += 1;
        }
        tempChar = getchar();
    }

    printf("[");
    for ( int i = 0; i < c-2; i++ ) {
        printf("%d,", numArray[c]);
    }
    printf("%d]\n", numArray[c-1]);

    return 0;
}
```

This doesn't work properly. It stops after reading one character.

Sample input and output:

```
Input: 1a3b5c7d9

Output: [0,0,0,9]

Desired output: [1,3,5,7,9]
```

Comment: How about using [`isdigit()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isdigit)?

Comment: I get the same problem.

Comment: Wait.... `i < i-2`...how is that supposed to work???

Comment: Fixed, supposed to be c. Miss typed while typing Question.

Comment: `printf("%d,", numArray[c]);` ---> `printf("%d,", numArray[i]);`

Comment: http://ideone.com/59AuMT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in code

```
printf("%d,", numArray[c]);
```

Must be

```
printf("%d,", numArray[i]);
```

And the print loop can simply be

```
printf("[");
for ( int i = 0; i < c; i++ )
{
    printf("%d%c", numArray[i], (i<c-1)? ',' : ']');
}
printf("\n");
```

Take note that your code is managing only one digit value. E.g. `45` is managed as `4` and `5`.

Comment: Yeah, that's it. So the array itself was correct, the printing was wrong.